# Solr query date not equal

Tags: solr

I have a solrcloud schema with field that is path_hierarchy. Example data that it is storing,

```
"last_update": [
      "/1/2015-09-22T10:59:46.000Z",
      "/2/2015-09-23T10:59:46.000Z",
      "/3/2015-09-24T10:59:46.000Z",
      "/4/2015-09-28T10:59:46.000Z",
],
```

Is there a way for me to query where the date is not between 2015-09-23 to 2015-09-24?
Something like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date < 2015-09-23 or date > 2015-09-24` for SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
-last_update:[2015-09-23T23:59:59.999Z TO 2015-09-23T23:59:59.999Z+1DAY]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use range query and NOT operator; so you'll have something like

```
NOT date:[2015-09-23T23:59:59.999Z TO 2015-09-23T23:59:59.999Z+1DAY]
```

Please see https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, maybe because my field type is path_hierarchy?